# T-SQL - query ordering by year,month not working as I need

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this simple query that supposed to return a list of records listed in descent order by year and month, starting from year and month provided parameters:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where year <= @year 
  and month <= @month 
order by year desc, month desc
```

The problem is that if I provide year=2019 and month=2, it returns:

```
2019,2
2019,1
2018,2
2018,1
2017,2
2017,1 etc
```

As you may suppose, I need that it returns instead:

```
2019,2
2019,1
2018,12
2018,11
2018,10 etc
```

I am not managing to see how to figure it. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where year < @year or
      (year = @year and month <= @month)
order by year desc, month desc;
```

An alternative would use arithmetic, essentially counting months:

```
where year * 12 + month <= @year * 12 + @month
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, thank you VERY much! Both solutions worked like a charm! I picked the first one though as it looks a bit more SQLish and less Mathish! :D

Answer (score 0):

Following does the job as far as your year and month are not numeric data type:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    @mytable 
where 
    [year]+case when len(month) = 1 then '0' + month else month end 
    <= @year+case when len(@month) = 1 then '0' + @month else @month end
order by 
    [year]+case when len(month) = 1 then '0' + month else month end desc
```